# Definition of differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

**Definition of Differentiable functions**
A real-valued function $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is differentiable at a point $x_0 \in (a,b)$ if  $$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} {f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)\over h} = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} {f(x)-f(x_0)\over x-x_0} $$

I am wondering why we have that above equality. 
Here is how I understand:

$$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} {f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)\over h} = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} {f(x_0 +x - x_0)-f(x_0)\over x-x_0}
=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} {f(x)-f(x_0)\over x-x_0}$$

Please help me understand the concept. Thanks!

Comment: That's how I think of it, but if there's a more rigorous way of thinking about it, I would be interested.

Comment: @Clarinetist I have been looking for a rigorous proof of it but haven't found it yet.

Comment: Change of variables is plenty rigorous

Comment: @charlotte would you elaborate about the definition if you know.

Answer (score 2):

The second definition states that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - x_{0}| < \delta \implies |\frac{f(x) - f(x_{0})}{x - x_{0}}| < \epsilon$. Note that this is the definition of a limit being applied.

In the first case, we are saying $h < \delta$, so $|x_{0} - (x_{0} + h)| < \delta$. So let $x = x_{0} + h$. Again, the limit is the same. That's really all that is going on.

Comment: Thanks! Why we need to let $x=x_0 + h$ ?

Comment: Because $x$ is what is approaching $x_{0}$. Consider $x = x_{0} + h$. So $x \to x_{0}$ is equivalent to saying $h \to 0$.